# get return value from a function php using oops

Tags: php, oop

I have code below, where i need to get the return value in a variable outside a class and also its print with respective code.

http://codepad.org/mAlhYBll

and below is raw code.

```
<?php
    class test {
        public function kk() {
            echo "Whats up :";
            return "Hello";
        }
    }

    $obj = new test();
    $obj->kk();

    $abc = $obj->kk();
?>
```

Now how can i get value returned from a function added an image below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `echo $abc`.  The program is printing something else since you're echoing `What's up` within the method, remove that.

Comment: Correct, though don't delete the echo, just print $abc as that is your problem.

Comment: @Andy yes, rather I shouldn't have asked to delete the other `echo` statement :-D

Comment: see guys: i have updated the code, but i dont want to remove that echo statement from function.. is there any possiblities.

http://codepad.org/M2R8xzH8

Comment: @Rafee you don't need to remove the `echo`, but you should be echoing `$abc` which receives the return value from the method.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you've done - although you call "kk()" twice, which is not nneeded, so drop line 13.